# Referencing 'host'

Tags: createjs

I have a mouse-down event listener on an object that starts a createjs.Ticker. I need to pass a reference to the object in the 'tick' function, or at least be able to access that object. This is the code block:

```
this.obj.on("mousedown", function(event) {
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",
        this.flowControl);
});
```

I need to be able to get a reference to obj object from the flowControl function:

```
this.flowControl = function(e) {
   api.onButtonPress(this.obj);
}
```

...the 'this' in the flowControl function is the Ticker event and I cannot find how to reference the obj object

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter of the `on` method is scope. If you don't pass one in, it uses the firing object as the scope.

Additionally, you are using both `on` and `addEventListener`. I recommend sticking with `on()`.

```
this.obj.on("mousedown", function(event) {
    createjs.Ticker.on("tick", 
        this.flowControl, this);
}, this);
```

Your `mousedown` and `tick` events will fire in the same scope, so you can reference `this.obj` from both functions.